# Сломался символ крестика в сообщениях системы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

[Как проверить, что строка является числом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/938502/15479)

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это просто локализованный крестик

Comment: @АндрейNOP https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323213/260198 на en сайтах тоже сломано.